# addEventListener working in console but not working in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code for a book library.
https://jsfiddle.net/j5mxws4n/

I'm at the point of working with the 'read' sign where I want to add an event on click to change the icon from tick to X.
I can do it through google console but when I do it in JS, I get a null error which is kinda weird.

the way I'm trying to do it it:

```
document.querySelector('#sign).addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
if(e.target.innerHTML === '✔'){
        e.target.innerHTML = 'X'}
else{
        e.target.innerHTML = '✔'
})
```

I get a null error even if I just type:

```
let sign = document.querySelector('#sign').textContent;
```

Comment: The code you've placed here on SO has a syntax error; please include a [mre] here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external website. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: You are adding the `sign` element dynamically.  Since one does not exist when the page first loads, the `eventListener` does not get added to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/h43ztr1k/

- Change the sign to a class since IDs must be unique  -
- You need to delegate so add the click to the container

Also remember to preventDefault or the page will jump

```js
document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  let tgt = e.target, cls = e.target.classList;
  console.log(cls)
  if (cls.contains("delete")) tgt.closest("tr").remove()
  else if (cls.contains("sign")) {
    e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent === "✔" ? "":"✔";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You forgot to add the closing '
document.querySelector('#sign).addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
```

This line should be written like this

```
document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelector('#sign').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
if(e.target.innerHTML === '✔'){
        e.target.innerHTML = 'X'}
else{
        e.target.innerHTML = '✔'
}})
let sign = document.querySelector('#sign').textContent;
```

```html
<h1>click on check icon </h1>
<div id='sign'>✔</div>
```

Comment: The ID will not be unique and will not be available on page load (dynamic) so your code will not work.  see my answer for a working solution